# limit UITextField to specific number

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitextfield, xamarin

I have a UITextField and I want to limit the user to only input decimal numbers that are between 0.0 and 24.00.
The main idea is that user is entering Hours in that field.  So It can't go over 24 hours in a day.

is it possible to automatically enter a decimal after 2 digits?  So when a user enter "18" for example, a decimal "." automatically shows up.

Right now, I am limiting the user to only enter full hours. So they can only enter 2 digits. I really need to change that.  This is what I have now.

```
txtFld_Hours.ShouldChangeCharacters = (textField, range, replacementString) => {
    var newLength = textField.Text.Length + replacementString.Length - range.Length;
    return newLength <= 2;
};
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you considered using a UIDatePicker control?

Comment: Yes I have. I am trying to stay away from all standard iOS pickers.  I also have a date selection and I am using popup calendar library instead date picker.  For time, I would either like user to enter the hours OR i would have to make my own keyboard where some buttons are disabled and all that. I would rather not do that.

Comment: Wow. Staying away from standard controls? And your rationale behind that is?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.iOS and making multi-platform app.  If I use date picker in iOS, I can't do the same in android or windows.  If I have my own style, they are same across all platforms.

Comment: Customise your app for each platform. And Android and Windows Phone have their own date pickers.

Comment: That's what I don't want to do. I want the app UI exactly same across all platforms.  I'm not sure if you are familiar with the app waze.  They have the same thing. Completely customized UI so they are same all across.  I believe user going from one to another, it makes it really easy

Comment: I understand your rationale for wanting the same interface across all platforms for your particular application, though I have to point out that native controls are just as familiar (if not more familiar) to the user since they're used by other app creators and the system app creators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is possible of course, but like other people mentioned, it would be much better to use `UIDatePicker` control for a time picker (it even handles localisation for you on iOS, as some countries use 12-hour time with AM/PM marker for example). Even MonoTouch documentation says there are differences between platforms and you should structure your code in a way that only the difference in UI code is written for each platform, but all other code is common to all platforms.

But if you absolutely have to do this on your own, this requires a bit more complex solution, so we cannot write this for you directly. Search over **GitHub** for some code samples, I am sure that you can easily convert **Objective-C** into **MonoTouch**, since it is supposed to be a 1:1 mapping of the API.

Here are a few things on where to start:

- See [`IUITextFieldDelegate`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.IUITextFieldDelegate) interface documentation (which you already know about)
- Update the `ShouldBeginEditing` method with code that will handle the dot.

  - When 2 characters are reached, add the dot programatically and move the cursor behind the dot using [`SelectedTextRange`](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3AMonoTouch.UIKit.UITextField.SelectedTextRange) property.
  - The maximum length of the text, should now be 5.
  - Handle the automatic removal of the dot when text length is 3 and user taps backspace.

Following this and you should have your own `UITextField` with your custom hour picker.